# Error [: ==: unary operator expected in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to run shell script in which I am matching two string values but getting above error. Can you please help me how to resolve this?

Example:

run command:

```
sh script.sh AMPIL Group_1
```

So here `Group_1` is a `Execution_order`

I am using below shell script:

```
    if [ $Execution_Order == "Group_1" ]
    then
        rm sqoop_queries_meta_data_Group_1.txt
        echo $sqoop_queries >> sqoop_queries_meta_data_Group_1.txt
    elif [ $Execution_Order == "Group_2" ]
    then
        rm sqoop_queries_meta_data_Group_2.txt
        echo $sqoop_queries >> sqoop_queries_meta_data_Group_2.txt
    else 
        rm sqoop_queries_meta_data.txt
        echo $sqoop_queries >> sqoop_queries_meta_data.txt
    fi
```

If else part is not working and giving the above error. Can you please correct me?

Comment: Copy and paste your script to https://shellcheck.net

Comment: @Shivam : HolgerJust already pointed out the error in your script. For the general case, have a look at `man test` to see what operations you have at your disposable between `[ .... ]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string comparison operator of the `test` command, (i.e. the `[ ... ]` syntax is defined as a single equals sign. Some shells (including `bash`) also accept the double-equals but it's not part of the original POSIX spec.

Thus, you might want to change your queries to:

```
if [ "$Execution_Order" = "Group_1" ]
then
    rm sqoop_queries_meta_data_Group_1.txt
    echo "$sqoop_queries" >> sqoop_queries_meta_data_Group_1.txt
elif [ "$Execution_Order" = "Group_2" ]
then
    rm sqoop_queries_meta_data_Group_2.txt
    echo "$sqoop_queries" >> sqoop_queries_meta_data_Group_2.txt
else 
    rm sqoop_queries_meta_data.txt
    echo "$sqoop_queries" >> sqoop_queries_meta_data.txt
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for comment but it is still going to elif part while i am giving Execution_order = Group_1

Comment: @Shivam : Perhaps the variable does not contain what you think. Did you run it with `set -x`?

Comment: Also make sure that you use consistent casing for variable names throughout your script. `$Execution_order` is a different variable from `$Execution_Order`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need an `elif` in this special example. Also, I don't understand why you first remove a file and then append to that very file. How about

```
eo="${Execution_Order:+_$Execution_Order}"
echo "$sqoop_queries" > "sqoop_queries_meta_data$eo.txt"
```

? The main difference is that if `Execution_Order` would be, say, Group_3, it would create a file sqoop_queries_meta_data_Group3 in my solution, while it would write to sqoop_queries_meta_data.txt in your attempt, but if this is a problem in your context, this can easily be fixed.

Explanation: The `:+` sets `eo` to empty, if `Execution_Order` is empty, and to `_$Execution_Order` otherwise.